# Declare bean with @Valid

Tags: validation, spring-boot

is there a way to valid the properties bean?

```
@Data
public class ProjectProperties {
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
}
```

create the bean with:

```
@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "project")
@Valid
public ProjectProperties getProjectProperties() {
    return new ProjectProperties();
}
```

and my application.properties:

```
project.description =
```

Is there different way to make the validation work?

Comment: You want the validation at the time of application startup or `getProjectProperties()` call?

Comment: yes. when it is autowired:    @Autowired ProjectProperties projectProperty;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Data
@Validated
public class ProjectProperties {
    @NotBlank
    @NotEmpty
    private String description;
}
```

Comment: my example was simplified.  But I like to keep that structure where the bean can be created with different property prefix.  In the example, it was "project".   and ProjectProperties would have more fields to it instead of just description

Comment: did you try adding @Validated ?